# Acumatica - navigate link to Emails from GIs

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

We have created a GI which displays data from CR Activity Tables, for the Subject field we want to add navigate link to Email Activity screen.
So when we try to select navigation parameters, we could not able to load value in drop down control, please refer the attached screenshot.

Also the default navigation is not working for the subject field.

[image: GI Navigation Parameters]